# 2 Lights in my kitchen. One light is controlled by 2 switches on opposite walls. The other light is on a separate switch. Can I connect the 2?

Tags: wiring, lighting

[image]

Could I connect the red light to the blue circuit, simply by using a couple wire connectors in the 2-gang? If I can, I'd remove the red switch, and just use a double-wide 1-gang toggle switch cover.

Comment: We'll need to know a bit more about the wiring in the left box. Please revise to add a clear description and/or a photo.

Comment: It really depends.  If the power goes to the light, and there's a runner to the switch then no.  If power goes to the switch box first, and then to the light, then it's fairly simple to do what you want.

Comment: It can be done but as Chris and Isherwood have mentioned we need to know how it’s wired. It may require pulling a cable from 1 fixture to the other , can you pull the switches out and provide photos of the wiring we might get enough info to guide you through the process.

Comment: Can you post photos of the insides of the boxes involved please?